# Specifying only allowed zone for RadDock of WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, telerik

I would like to limit the area that a window/tool window can dock in RadDock. I have tried the following code but no luck.

```
dock.DockStateChanging += new DockStateChangingEventHandler(dock_DockStateChanging);

...

void dock_DockStateChanging(object sender, DockStateChangingEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.NewWindow.Name == "restricted window")
                e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to restrict dockable zones of window/tool window with RadDock for WinForms

Answer (score 0):

To limit the area where a window can be docked, you should use the DragDropService of RadDock. More information and example of this is available in the [Telerik UI for WinForms documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-architecture-and-features-using-the-dragdropservice.html)